# This code causes an Application not responding dialog

Tags: java, arrays, android-studio, for-loop, android-anr-dialog

I am making a checkers game and the following code causes an application not responding dialog when in operation. How can i make the code efficient and remove the Anr dialog.

```
public void drawPawns() {
        for(int i=0; i<playableTileView.length; i++) {
            if(playableTile[i].getIsTaken() == 1) playableTileView[i].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.white_pawn);
            else if(playableTile[i].getIsTaken() == -1) playableTileView[i].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.brown_pawn);
            else if(playableTile[i].getIsTaken() == 2) playableTileView[i].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.white_queen);
            else if(playableTile[i].getIsTaken() == -2) playableTileView[i].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.brown_queen);
            else playableTileView[i].setBackgroundResource(0);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Check for any possible exception such as NullPointerException thrown. Check the error logs.

Comment: There is no NullPointerException in the logs, if it where to be that it would have crashed the app instead of an Anr.

Answer (score 0):

How many playableTileView are there?
If it is more than 5 then You need to use handler as setBackground is a UI heavy operation also you can't use it background thread here. Also you can check and store the previous set background and set only when it is required.

I am assuming you have added proper drawable for all image-resolution specially hdpi, xhdpi and xxhdpi

```
handler.postDelayed(()->{
if(playableTile[i].getIsTaken() == 1) playableTileView[i].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.white_pawn);
        else if(playableTile[i].getIsTaken() == -1) playableTileView[i].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.brown_pawn);
        else if(playableTile[i].getIsTaken() == 2) playableTileView[i].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.white_queen);
        else if(playableTile[i].getIsTaken() == -2) playableTileView[i].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.brown_queen);
        else playableTileView[i].setBackgroundResource(0);
},10);
```

Comment: Yes it's more than 5, actually the forloop runs 50 times as there are 50 playable squares it perform checks on

Comment: Its huge try with above solution ANR should stop.
also one optimize tip store lastIsTaken in playableTile object.
update only when playableTile.getIstaken != playbleLastIsTaken.
take any default lastIsTaken value which cannot be same first time.

Comment: Alright I will do that and get back to you

Comment: I just tried your suggestion but the Anr still occurs. The optimized tip you suggested, I  wouldn't be able to do that without major changes on my code . Please I will like if you have any other suggestions.

Comment: have you added postDelayed inside for loop or outside.?
If it is inside for loop and still happening then I suggest please check other area too.
quick way is override setBackgroundResource in playableTileView and call super when background is changed and ignored if it is same.

Comment: Okay i will do that and get back to you.